# Java - developer exception error

Tags: java, exception

here is the thing:

- I have a DB that serves as a scoreborad;
- I have a button that updates the DB with the new scores;
- I have a "developer exception" that throws a SQLException whenever the score is low and can't replace any score in the scoreboard (DB);

The problem:

- In the scoreboard i have the following scores:
  6 - 4 - 3 - 2 - 1
- Then i get a new score bigger than 6 (67, for example) and the scoreboard is updated as the following:
  6 - 67 - 3 - 2 - 1
- Aparently the problem lies in the developer exception, because when i remove it the scoreboard is updated correctly, namely:
  67 - 4 - 3 - 2 - 1

Other situation:

- In the scoreboard i have the following scores:
  6 - 5 - 2 - 1 - 0
- Then i get the score 4 and the scoreboard is updated as the following:
  6 - 5 - 2 - 4 - 0

In other words what's really apening here is that the verification jumps 1 field.

So how can i solve this without removing the exception??

Here is the code in the button:

```
try
    {
        Connection conec=DriverManager.getConnection(hostname,username,password); //<-- Conecçao com a base de dados
        stm=conec.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE); //<-- Conecção com as tabelas
      //------------Aquisição dos dados------------------//
        SQL="SELECT * FROM DEMOLION.MINER";
        res=stm.executeQuery(SQL);
      //-------------------------------------------------//
        res.first();
        nome=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduza o mone que deseja registar:","Jogador1");
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("Jogos RPG Maker/Miner mapa/Game.exe"));
        pontuacao=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduza a pontuação obtida:","0");
        pontos=Integer.parseInt(pontuacao);
        do
        {
            pontos_insuf();
            dbpontos=res.getInt("PONTUACOES");
            System.out.println("pt="+pontos+"db="+dbpontos);
            if(pontos>dbpontos)
            {
                res.updateInt("PONTUACOES",pontos);
                res.updateString("NOME",nome);
                res.updateRow();
            }
            if(pontos<dbpontos || pontos==dbpontos)
            {
                res.next();
            }
        }
        while(pontos<dbpontos);
    }
    catch (IOException | SQLException ex)
    {
        MsgBox.show(ex.getMessage(),"AVISO", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    finally
    {
        try 
        {
            stm.close();
            res.close();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e3)
        {
            MsgBox.show(e3.getMessage(),"AVISO", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

here is the developer exception:

```
private void pontos_insuf() throws SQLException{
if(!res.next())
{
    throw new SQLException("Obteve uma pontuação insuficiente para superar pontuações anteriores!");
} }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `developer exception`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`next` will advance the row pointer, but since you called `first`, the row pointer is already at the beginning, so you skip the first row.  Your code should work if you remove the call to `res.first();`

Comment: You're calling `res.next()` in the second if-statement, so you are making a double-jump again.  Remove the second if-statement:             `if(pontos<dbpontos || pontos==dbpontos) { res.next(); }`